# passing arguments to a cURL shell script file

Tags: python, shell, curl, command-line-arguments

I do not have much experience with shell or python scripts so I am looking for some help on how I can accomplish this.

Goal:

Pass arguments to a shell or python script file that will be used to perform either a cURL Post request or a python post request.

Let's say I go the python route and the filename is api.py

```
import json,httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.example.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('POST', '/message', json.dumps({
       "where": {
         "devicePlatform": "andriod"
       },
       "data": {
         "body": "Test message!",
         "subject": "Test subject"
       }
     }), {
       "X-Application-Id": "XXXXXXXXX",
       "X-API-Key": "XXXXXXXX",
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
     })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print result
```

How would I go about passing in arguments to for the body and subject values and how would that look via command line?

Thanks

Comment: Well, back up for a second: how would you grab command line arguments to a Python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using argparse to parse command line arguments

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import json

import httplib

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-s", "--subject", help="Subject data", required=True)
parser.add_argument("-b", "--body", help="Body data", required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.example.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('POST', '/message', json.dumps({
       "where": {
         "devicePlatform": "andriod"
       },
       "data": {
         "body": args.body,
         "subject": args.subject,
       }
...
```

On the CLI it would look like

```
python script.py -b "Body" -s "Subject"
```

Comment: Ok this makes sense. I will give it a shot tomorrow and if I have any other questions I will post another comment here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This worked great. How would you approach for a curl script.  I am assuming it would look similar to   curl  script.sh | bash and the arguments here but how would those look in the actual script? I am assuming they are different than the argument parser example above.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. Are you asking how would you replicate all the functionality of curl in a python script?

Comment: Here is an example. Most of this request would have constant values like the user and password content type etc. This curl request could be in a .sh file bash script. The subject, description and email values would need to be variables. Is there a way to accomplish what we did with the arguments in a bash script. If not how could I take this example below (from a common api) and accomplish in python. Authentication is Basic Access Authentication and must be base64 encoded prior to be passed as an authorization header (-u user@yourcompany.com:test) . Example below

Comment: curl -u user@yourcompany.com:test -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "helpdesk_ticket": { "description": "Details about the issue...", "subject": "Support Needed...", "email": "tom@outerspace.com", "priority": 1, "status": 2 }, "cc_emails": "ram@freshdesk.com,diana@freshdesk.com" }' -X POST http://domain.freshdesk.com/helpdesk/tickets.json

Comment: I think if you take a look over at the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) documentation it will help you with further implementation needs. There are default arguments, different variable types and plenty of other features to help you finish your project. I'm not trying to blow off the question I just think that complete implementation of your script is beyond the scope of this stackoverflow ticket and that it would be a useful learning experience for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html). An example with the subject:

```
import json,httplib
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('subject', help='string containing the subject')
args = parser.parse_args()

connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.example.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('POST', '/message', json.dumps({
       "where": {
         "devicePlatform": "andriod"
       },
       "data": {
         "body": "Test message!",
         "subject": args.subject
       }
     }), {
       "X-Application-Id": "XXXXXXXXX",
       "X-API-Key": "XXXXXXXX",
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
     })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print result
```